# No he podido enviar datos del formulario de Whatsapp Business Flow al endpoint de intercambio de datos,

Tags: flask, whatsapp-webhook

estoy usando la libreria pywa en una aplicacion Flask (python3). He logrado recibir el envío POST de Whatsapp Business Flow, decodificarlo, extraer el contenido , generar la respuesta y enviarla codificada de nuevo a Whatsapp Business Flow. sin embargo tengo problemas con los datos que vienen en el request.
En la acción 'on-click-action' espero enviar la informacion que introduzca el usuario en el formulario, pero siempre recibo  ${form.parentname} como dato (no el valor del campo)

El código en el footer es:

```
                        "type": "Footer",
                        "label": "Siguiente",
                        "on-click-action": {
                            "name": "data_exchange",
                            "payload" : {
                                "parentname":"${form.parentname}"
                            }
                        },
                        "enabled":true
                     }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al presionar siguiente, el  endpoint recibe data={'parentname': '${form.parentname}'} cuando debería ser :  data={'parentname': 'Alejandro'}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Me respondo a mi mismo,
El error se presentaba porque el footer estaba por fuera del children del formulario, se soluciona moviendo el footer adentro del Form, tal como se ve en la imagen.

Gracias a https://stackoverflow.com/users/3716153/gafi por su respuesta en stack overflow en ingles.

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78220614/whatsapp-business-api-whatsapp-flow-problem-sendig-payload-to-endpoint)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]